# CQRS Pattern with .NET API - Separating the request object from the command/query

Tags: c#, .net, api, cqrs, mediatr

Concerning the use of the CQRS pattern in a .NET API I've seen some examples where the request is deserialized directly into the command/query and then it's sent off for handling, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrder(CreateOrderCommand command)
{
    var result = await _mediator.Send(command);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

In other examples, some kind of dto or request object is instead used and then fed into the constructor of the command/query, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrder(CreateOrderDto model)
{
    var command = new CreateOrderCommand(model.orderNumber, model.firstName...);
    var result = await _mediator.Send(command);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The first approach looks more appealing to me as it's one less model and line of code. Is there a reason why you might use the second approach and separate the request object from the command object?

Comment: this is offtopic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a reason why you might use the second approach and separate the request object from the command object?

Yes - the domain model changes at a faster cadence than your publicly facing interface.

`CreateOrderDto` is an in memory representation of the request payload; the schema of which is something that is documented for client use.  Making "breaking" changes to it is hard, because its a change that impacts all of your consumers.

`CreateOrderCommand` is an in memory representation of data used to communicate between your application and your domain model.  The distance between the two concerns is greatly reduced, and so it is a lot easier to coordinates changes at both ends of the conversation.